# Using forkJoin as lettable operator in RxJS 6 pipe

Tags: rxjs6

**End Goal**
I have a user/device registration method. In it I need to:

1. Check whether local storage is ready
2. If so, check separately for deviceId and token
3. If either deviceId or token are not found, call registration endpoint

**Where I'm At**
During building, and for simplicity, I was not dealing with tokenization. I was only working with deviceId and the below worked/works perfectly fine.

I call my isStorageReady helper method, check the response, then call my getDeviceId helper method, and check that response.

```
this.isStorageReadyAsync()
    .pipe(
        map(storageResponse => {
            // check storageResponse
            // if undefined throw error
            // error picked up by retryPipeline
            // if retryPipeline exhausted picked up 
            // by errorPipeline and stream is stopped
            if (storageRes === undefined ||
                storageRes['LOCALSTORAGE'] === undefined ||
                storageRes['LOCALSTORAGE'] === '') throw 'storageRes or 
                storageRes.LOCALSTORAGE are undefined or empty';
        }),
        flatMap(_ => this.getStoredDeviceIdAsync()),
        map(deviceId => {
            return iif(() => deviceId === undefined || 
                             deviceId === null || 
                             deviceId === '',
                       // no deviceId stored on device
                       // register device to get deviceId
                       this.registerDeviceAsync(), 
                       // deviceId found in local storage
                       of({id: deviceId, new: false}))
        }),
        this.storeDeviceIdPipeline, // store deviceId
        this.retryPipeline, // retry if e.g. experiencing network issues
        this.errorPipeline // catch and handle errors
    )
```

**Where I'm Stuck**
I have a second helper method, `getStoredTokenAsync()` which I would like called in parallel with `getStoredDeviceIdAsync()`. I've tried using `forkJoin` and passing an array into the `map` operator that follows but my typescript linter doesn't like this at all. Everything before forkJoin gets underlined as though it is an error and the error reads as follows:

> Argument of type OperatorFunction is not assignable to parameter of type OperatorFunction. Type void is not assignable to type {}.

So I don't quite understand. I was hoping to use something like this:

```
...
forkJoin([this.getStoredDeviceIdAsync(), this.getStoredTokenAsync()]),
map(authArr => {
   let deviceId = authArr[0];
   let token = authArr[1];
   ...
})
...
```

Comment: Does the map in the third line return sonething? I can see the throw but not the returned value

Comment: If no error it just returns the observable as passed to it. Perhaps not the best/most declarative way to construct it on my end. So essentially map is just checking for an error and throwing it. If no error then map doesn't do anything.

Comment: Checking for errors in the map is ok.In any case it should return something ( storageResponse ) or it will show the underline

Comment: The type void is probably the map. I suggest you to use the flatMapTo operator to declare that you're not intrested to the previous input

Comment: Ah! Returning storageResponse does solve the first issue. Thank you. Haven't heard of flatMapTo. Where is the documentation on it? Doing some googling and can't find it. Also - any input on using forkJoin to run the two helper methods in parallel?

Comment: If the helper methods themselves do return an ovservable you can store them into an array as you wrote before. Just make sure to not use forkjoin directly inside a pipe, since forkjoin is not an operator. map into it using merge/exhaust/switch/concatMap operators

Comment: With `forkJoin` you can pipe both streams inside `forkJoin` and `map` them as usual. `flatMap` is now called `mergeMap`

Comment: Sweet! Embedding `forkJoin` inside of `mergeMapTo` works great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to both commenters, LookForAngular and Julius Dzidzevičius, for helping put this together! Am providing the complete answer here in case this is helpful to others. Also providing more of the code for some additional context.

Before the `mergeMapTo` call, there is some generic response checking. The output from that does not get consumed so using `mergeMapTo` is appropriate (implies that whatever came before it is irrelevant to what's happening inside of `mergeMapTo`).

`mergeMap` essentially flattens the inner observable, which is provided by my `iif` call. The output from `mergeMap` gets routed to my storage pipeline (which is just a `map` call) which handles all of the logic associated with user authentication, etc.

```
pipe(
    ...
    mergeMapTo(forkJoin([this.getStoredDeviceIdAsync(), this.getStoredTokenAsync()])),
    mergeMap(authArr => {
        let deviceId = authArr[0];
        let token = authArr[1];
        return iif(() => deviceId === undefined || deviceId === null || deviceId === '' ||
                         token === undefined || token === null || token === '',
                         this.registerDeviceAsync(), // register device to get deviceId and token
                         of({deviceId: deviceId, token: token, new: false})) 
    }),
    this.storeDeviceIdTokenPipeline,
    this._config.retryPipeline, // generic retryWhen procedure
    this._config.errorPipeline // generic catchError procedure
)
```